# Javascript Regular expression for custom URL?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have 3 URL scenarios

1. normal urls:

   - http://example.com,
   - https://example.com,
   - https://example.com/products/1234,
   - https://example.com/products?category=shoes&limit=10
2. url with context variable:

   - https://example.com/products/{$context.productId}
3. whole url is context variable:

   - {$varContext.getProductUrl}

I have to validate input URL to match above 3 scenarios.

I have written regex but which is not working for all scenarios.

```py
^((?:http(s){0,1}://[\\w\\-\\.:/\$\{\}=\?&]+)|(?:\{\$[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+\}))$
```

Could any one please help with this?

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: Do you want to test the literal text: {$varContext.getProductUrl} ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you made a very simple mistake. Stopped 1% away from the finish line.

```
^((?:http(s){0,1}:\/\/[\w\-\.:/\${}=\?&]+)|(?:{\$[a-zA-Z]+.[a-zA-Z]+}))$
```

is the correct one you just forgot to escape the / to denote (mean) a literal /. Mistake appears right after `^((?:http(s){0,1}:`

Next time use a site like [Regex101, a site to help you test your regex](https://regex101.com/) in case you didn't know.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from escaping the forward slashes after http://, you are escaping the backslash in the character class. `\\w` would match a backslash and a `w`. This part `\\-\\` would match a range from \ till \ which would match a backslash.

That would match for example `http://w\.:/${}=?&`

As an addition, you could make a few adjustments to your regex.

- `(s){0,1}` can be written as `https?`
- The character class `[\\w\\-\\.:/\$\{\}=\?&]` can be written as `[\w.:/${}=?&-]` without the escaping of `.$?` and the hyphen can be moved to the beginning or at the end. `\\` would match a backslash.
- If you don't need the capturing group `()` you could omit that and only use an alternation `|`
- You could use the `/i` to get a case insensitive match and the character class would become `[a-z]`
- Escape the dot `\.` to match it literally

For example:

```
const regex = /^https?:\/\/[\w.:/${}=?&-]+|{\$[a-z]+\.[a-z]+}$/i;
```

See the [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rtt4fd/1)